# Access PCI memory BAR with low latency (Linux)

Tags: linux, memory, linux-device-driver, mmap, pci

### Background:

I have a PCI card, which is basically a clock. It gets the time by GPS and saves the current time in a certain register.

### Goal:

I want to read a limited number of registers/bytes (for example the current time) over and over again, with the **lowest possible latency**. (The clock provides very high precision and I think I will loose precision the higher the latency is.). The operating system is RedHat. The programming language is C/C++. I also want to write to the device memory, whereby latency is not an issue.

### Possible Ways to go:

I see these ways. If you see another, please tell me:

1. Writing a Linux kernel module driver, which creates a character device (or one character device for each register to read). Then a user space application can do a "read" on the /dev/ file(s).
2. DMA
3. mmap the sysfs resourceX file to user space by a user space application (systemcall). (like [here](https://github.com/billfarrow/pcimem/blob/master/pcimem.c) for example)
4. Write a Linux kernel module driver which implements a mmap file operation.

### Questions:

1. Which is the way with the lowest latency when it comes to the actual reading of the register? I am aware that mmap causes a lot of overhead in the kernel, but as far as I understand that is only for initialisation.
2. Is way 3 a legit way to go? It looks like a hack to me. How can I determine the /sys/ path automatically from the application?
3. Is there a difference between way 3 and 4? I am new to PCI driver programming and I think I didn't really understand how way 4 works. I read [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch15.html) (and other chapters of that book), but maybe you can give me a hint or an example. I would appreciate that.

Comment: In Linux there is a VDSO mechanism, one of the purpose of which is to provide a fastest way of `gettimeofday()`. If your clock driver can update a variable inside VDSO it will be fastest way ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 3 or 4 should work fine. There’s no difference between them with respect to latency. Latency would be in the order of 100 ns.

Method 4 would be needed if you need to initialize the device, or control which applications are allowed to access it, or enforce one reader at a time, etc. Method 3 does seem like a bit of a hack because it skips all of this. But it is simpler if you don’t need such things.

A character device is definitely higher latency, because it requires a kernel transition each time the device is read.

The latency of a DMA method depends entirely on how frequently the device writes the time to memory. It is lower latency for the CPU to access memory than MMIO, but if the device only does DMA once a millisecond, then that would be your latency. Also, that method generates a lot of useless DMA traffic, since the CPU would read the value far less often than it is written.

Comment: I didn’t address the second part of question 2. Perhaps someone else can help with that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your last sentence: "Also, that method generates a lot of useless DMA traffic, since the CPU would read the value far less often than it is written." Just to be sure I understood that correctly: The traffic is caused by the writes of the device and most of it is useless, because the CPU only reads some these writes. Correct?
Do you have a hint or example how to implement way 4? I did not find anything that helped me understand.

Comment: I would start with the same book you linked; it is what I have used in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @prl's answer...

Method 3 seems perfectly legit to me. That's what it's for. You may want to take a look at the kernel documentation file: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs-pci.txt

You can also use the `/sys` filesystem to find your device. First, note the vendor ID and device ID for your clock card (and subsystem vendor / device if necessary), then you can easily walk the `/sys/devices` hierarchy, looking for a matching device (using the `vendor`, `device`, etc. special files). Once you've found it, you presumably know which `resourceN` file to open from the device's data sheet, then `mmap` it at the appropriate offset and you're done.

That all assumes that your device is configured and enabled already. Typically a PCI device is not enabled to do anything when the system boots. Some driver needs to claim the device, and initialize / configure it. Once that is done, if the time is accessible just by reading a register or two, you can can go with method 3. (I'm not sure: it *may* be possible for a PCI device to be self-initializing but I've never seen one. I think probably something needs to enable its memory space at the very least. Likely that could be done from user-space if the setup is small enough / simple enough.)

The primary difference with method 4 is that the driver controlling the device would provide support for allowing the area to be `mmap`'d explicitly. For the user-space application, there is little difference between the two methods aside from the device name used. For method 4, the driver's probably going to provide a symbolic device name `/dev/clock0` or something like that for use by the user-space application (and presumably the application then doesn't need to go find the device, it would just *know* the device file name to open).

From user-space, you will do the `mmap` operation in much the same way with either method. In method 4, the driver internally supplies the physical address to map -- and possibly the offset -- instead of the generic PCI subsystem doing so, but either way, it's just `open` + `mmap`.

Linux driver programming is not terribly difficult, but there's a significant learning curve there if you haven't done it before, so I definitely wouldn't go with method 4 unless there were a real need to do so.